# How to solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = (x^2 - k_0)y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What method can be used to solve and plot the y over x graph satisfying:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = (x^2 - k_0)y$$

for a given constant $k_0$?

In particular, I am trying to reproduce the following:

[image]

Comment: The method of Frobenius is a good starting point.

Comment: Could you provide some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)? What's the source of the images? Do you have boundary conditions? (Etc.) This is just the time-independent Schrödinger equation for the harmonic oscillator, isn't it? How to solve it is explained in many quantum mechanics textbooks.

Comment: @HansLundmark the source is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjF20Pzicqg  (4:35). The graph is mentioned only briefly in passing. I believe the claim is that $\Psi$ will be unbounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$ for most but a small number of special values for E. I suppose that would mean *regardless of boundary conditions*, $\Psi$ is bounded and normalizable only for special points of E. How would one go about proving this *for all boundary conditions*?

Comment: Well, the condition is that the solution should be square integrable (so that you can normalize it), and that only happens for some values of $E$. And that's something that comes out when one tries to solve the ODE explicitly. It's a bit of a long story, but standard textbook material.

Comment: @HansLundmark thank you. I think what throws me off is this: suppose i have randomly selected E=1.23456789. Knowing only the differential relation $\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2} = (x^2-2E)\Psi$, how the heck is a graph of $\Psi$ plot-able given only this information?

Comment: There's two ways. One is to use the fact that this equation has known solutions called Hermite functions and use something like Mathematica that can calculate them. The other is to solve the differential equation numerically. Conceptually, that means dividing the graph interval into small steps, then choosing function values at each step such that the discrete approximations to the derivative satisfy the equation. This can usually be done iteratively starting from the initial condition.

Comment: @eyeballfrog thank you. I started with $\Psi_{x+\triangle x} = 2\Psi_{x} - \Psi_{x-\triangle x} + \Psi_x(x^2-2E)(\triangle x)^2$ but realized i needed 2 initial consecutive points to numerically continue the plot. What should these 2 initial values be chosen to be?

Comment: Since this is an even differential operator, a simple choice is $\Psi(0) = 1$, $\Psi'(0) = 0$ for the even solution and $\Psi(0) = 0$, $\Psi'(0) = 1$ for the odd one. This appears to be roughly how those graphs were created. Choosing a point $x_0$ and setting $\Psi(x_0) = \Psi(-x_0) = 1$ for the even and $\Psi(x_0) = -\Psi(-x_0) = 1$ will also work as long as $x_0$ isn't a zero of the solution, but it's very unlikely you'll pick such an $x_0$.

Comment: If you want to solve it analytically you can try to use the parabolic cylinder function https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html And graph it using mathematica

Answer (score 1):

Maple solves this in terms of [Whittaker functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function)
$$
y \left( x \right) ={{\it A}\;{{ M}_{k_0/4,1/4}\left({x}^{2}\right)}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {x}}}}+{{\it B}\;{{ W}_{k_0/4,1/4}\left({x}^{2}\right)}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {x
}}}}
$$
which are also given in terms of ${}_1F_1$ functions.

Comment: Wouldn't using the [Parabolic Cylinder Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html) be easier then using Whittaker functions?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way of solving for the second-order linear ordinary differential equation is [Frobenius Method](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html) if you don't know about special differential equations or special functions.

But if we have a bit of an idea about special differential equations, we could see with a little rearrangement
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}} &= \left( x^{2} - k_{0} \right) \cdot y\left( x \right)\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}} - \left( x^{2} - k_{0} \right) \cdot y\left( x \right) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
$$
that this is nothing more than an Differential Equation of the [Parabolic Cylinder Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html) ($\frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}y\left( x \right)}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}} + \left( v + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot x^{2} \right) \cdot y\left( x \right) = 0$), which satisfies the definition of the [Parabolic Cylinder Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html) $\operatorname{D_{v}}$ thus gives the solution
$$
\fbox{
$\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= c_{1} \cdot \operatorname{D_{\frac{k_{0} - 1}{2}}}\left( \sqrt{2} \cdot x \right) + c_{2} \cdot \operatorname{D_{-\frac{k_{0} + 1}{2}}}\left( \sqrt{2} \cdot x \cdot i \right)\\
\end{align*}$
}
$$
where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are constants and $i$ is the imaginary unit of complex numbers aka $i^{2} = -1$.

The [Parabolic Cylinder Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html) is closely related to the [Whittaker Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WhittakerFunction.html), as @GEdgar wrote. They are also very closely related to [Generalized Hypergeometric Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) $\operatorname{_{p}F_{q}}$, which also allows a nice solution in the form of the [Confluent Hypergeometric Function Of The First Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $\operatorname{U}$ for $\Re\left( x \right) \geq 0$:
$$
\fbox{
$\begin{align*}
y\left( x \right) &= c_{1} \cdot 2^{\frac{k_{0} - 1}{4}} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{4} \cdot x^{2}} \cdot \operatorname{U}\left( -\frac{k_{0} - 1}{4},\, \frac{1}{2},\, x^{2} \right) + c_{2} \cdot 2^{-\frac{k_{0} + 1}{4}} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{4} \cdot x^{2}} \cdot \operatorname{U}\left( \frac{k_{0} + 1}{4},\, \frac{1}{2},\, -x^{2} \right)\\
\end{align*}$
}
$$